# Is there an alternative to select case blocks that I can use in this situation?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am taking an introductory programming class using visual studio. This assignment has asked us to display a specific gif in a picture box depending on which random number is generated.

My program works, but I would really like to know if there is a way to accomplish the same thing with more efficiency or with less code.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
    Dim deposit As Integer
    Dim balance As Integer
    balance = CInt(lblbankAccount.Text)
    deposit = CInt(InputBox("Enter your deposit", "Dice Game"))
    lblbankAccount.Text = CStr(balance + deposit)
End Sub

Private Sub btnroll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnroll.Click
    Dim RandomNum As New Random
    Dim dice1, dice2, dice3, bet, bankroll, balance As Integer

    balance = CInt(lblbankAccount.Text)
    bet = CInt(txtbet.Text)
    dice1 = RandomNum.Next(1, 7)
    dice2 = RandomNum.Next(1, 7)
    dice3 = RandomNum.Next(1, 7)

    If dice1 = dice2 And dice1 = dice3 Then
        bankroll = (bankroll + (bet * 3))
    Else
        If dice1 = dice2 Or dice2 = dice3 Or dice1 = dice3 Then
            bankroll = (bankroll + (bet * 2))
        Else
            bankroll = (bankroll - bet)
        End If
    End If

    balance = bankroll + balance
    lblbankAccount.Text = CStr(balance)

    Select Case dice1
        Case 1
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide1.gif")
        Case 2
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide2.gif")
        Case 3
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide3.gif")
        Case 4
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide4.gif")
        Case 5
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide5.gif")
        Case 6
            Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide6.gif")
    End Select
    Select Case dice2
        Case 1
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide1.gif")
        Case 2
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide2.gif")
        Case 3
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide3.gif")
        Case 4
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide4.gif")
        Case 5
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide5.gif")
        Case 6
            PicBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide6.gif")
    End Select
    Select Case dice3
        Case 1
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide1.gif")
        Case 2
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide2.gif")
        Case 3
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide3.gif")
        Case 4
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide4.gif")
        Case 5
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide5.gif")
        Case 6
            PicBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide6.gif")
    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all select cases with the following:

```
Picbox1.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide" & dice1.ToString() & ".gif")
Picbox2.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide" & dice2.ToString() & ".gif")
Picbox3.Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide" & dice3.ToString() & ".gif")
```

Taking one step further, you can use a three elements `Integer` array to hold the dices instead of using three variables. Picture boxes can also be stored in an array. Then you can use for loops to scan the dices and pictures instead of repeating the code for each variable.

EDIT:

This is how it looks with arrays (and some LINQ):

```
Private Sub btnroll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnroll.Click
        Dim RandomNum As New Random
        Dim bet, bankroll, balance As Integer
        balance = CInt(lblbankAccount.Text)
        bet = CInt(txtbet.Text)
        Dim dices = New Integer() {RandomNum.Next(1, 7), RandomNum.Next(1, 7), RandomNum.Next(1, 7)}
        Dim Picboxes = New PictureBox() {Picbox1, Picbox2, Picbox3}
        Dim repetitions = dices.GroupBy(Function(dice) dice).Select(Function(x) New With {.dice = x.Key, .count = x.Count()}).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.count).FirstOrDefault().count
        Dim factor As Integer = IIf(repetitions = 1, -repetitions, repetitions)
        bankroll += bet * factor
        balance += bankroll
        lblbankAccount.Text = CStr(balance)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Picboxes(i).Image = Image.FromFile("DieSide" & dices(i).ToString & ".gif")
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As the image # (last character) equates to the case, same with pick box then there is a good chance that you could accomplish this with less code.

Perhaps a subroutine/method with the roll # and result passed through.